# Extjs 4: Render store data into Ext.form.Panel without using MVC framework

Tags: json, forms, extjs, extjs4, store

Below you will find an Ext.form.Panel that has two fields.  I chose two random fields in my model that have data.  They are not rendering in the form.  Note that I am not using MVC in the Extjs framework in this code.  **How can I get these fields to render?**  I've pasted the relevant output from the store.data.toSource() to show that I do in fact have data in my store, and only a single record.  To view the image with a little larger resolution, right click it and view in another tab.

> NOTE: .toSource() only works in Mozilla Firefox

I've tried executing this after creating the form, but it didn't work:

```
taskForm.getForm().loadRecord(store.getAt(0));
```

Code:

```
    var taskForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Task',
        id: 'form1',
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        renderTo: 'TaskEditForm',
        store: store,
        style: {
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '100px',
            'left': '10px'
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'label',
            labelAlign: 'right',
            name: 'project_id',
            fieldLabel: 'Project ID',
            width: 100
        }, {
            xtype: 'label',
            labelAlign: 'right',
            name: 'user_responsible',
            fieldLabel: 'User',
            width: 100
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Save Task Detail',
            handler: function (btn) {

                alert(store.data.toSource());

            }

        }]
    });
```

[image]

========

## Edit: @Evan

**This code gives the error below:**

taskForm.getForm().loadRecord(store.getAt(0));

**Error:**

```
TypeError: record is undefined
```

...

```
return this.setValues(record.data);  // ext-all-debug.js (line 109529)
```

**Line 109529:**

```
loadRecord: function(record) {
  this._record = record;
  return this.setValues(record.data);
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the documentation? `store.data` is a `MixedCollection` that holds a bunch of records. The documentation for the `load` method says:

> A class which handles loading of data from a server into the Fields of
>   an Ext.form.Basic.

You can't just throw in random parameters and expect stuff to work.

What you probably want is:

`form.getForm().loadRecord(store.getAt(0)); // Load the first store record into the form`

Comment: When I try taskForm.getForm().loadRecord(store.getAt(0)), I get this error in JS: "TypeError: record is undefined... return this.setValues(record.data);" <--- ext-all-debug.js (line 109529) ...

Comment: Ok, so do some debugging. What's in your store? `store.getCount();` Has it loaded yet?

Comment: Perfect!  My issue is that the count is 0.  I'm doing an autoLoad on my store, but I need to figure out why the Ext.form.Panel isn't waiting for the store to load.

Comment: Solution: I put the callback function (called "everythingLoaded") on my autoLoad of the store to a function name.  Then I called the loadRecord from that function.  autoLoad { callback: everythingLoaded } .. thanks @Evan!